# Bubblesort Algorithm - F#

Tags: f#

so I am trying to sort an array of values using the bubble sort algorithm. However, I am unable to find my mistake. Any advice?

```
let bubblesort<'a when 'a: comparison> (ar: Array<'a>): Unit =
    let rec sort (ar: Array<'a>): Unit =
        let mutable swapped = true
        for i in [|0.. ar.Length - 1|] do
            if ar.[i] > ar.[i+1] then
                let x = ar.[i]
                ar.[i] <- ar.[i+1]
                ar.[i+1] <- x
            swapped <- false
        if (not swapped) then sort ar
    sort ar
```

Comment: What is `Array<'a>`? System.Array is not generic and arrays in F# are `'a []`

Answer (score 2):

It looks fine to me, except for the actual loop. You should probably try something like this

```
for i in 0..ar.Length-2 do
```

You could also make your whole bubblesort function recursive and use it at the end. You dont need the second one, but its fine.

Answer (score 2):

When you comparing current item with the next one make sure its in array bounds. Also you should change flag within the if expression when you swap items.

```
let bubblesort<'a when 'a: comparison> (ar: Array<'a>): Unit =
    let rec sort (ar: Array<'a>): Unit =
        let mutable swapped = true
        for i in [|0.. ar.Length - 2|] do // here i + 1 should fit array
            if ar.[i] > ar.[i+1] then
                let x = ar.[i]
                ar.[i] <- ar.[i+1]
                ar.[i+1] <- x
                swapped <- false // and wrong indentation here here
        if (not swapped) then sort ar
    sort ar
```